# How to change the default position of quickfix window in Vim?

Tags: vim

**Setup:** MacVim with MiniBufExplorer plugin window spanning the entire top and Taglist plugin window on the right.

Due to the fact that I keep my Taglist on the right, whenever I open the quickfix window, it is positioned on the far right, below the Taglist window (with the same width as the Taglist window)

Is it possible to change the default opening position logic, so that the quickfix window will open below my main code window (down and to the left) or maybe span the entire width at the bottom of the Vim viewport?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

While it is not possible to change the default split-window behavior
of the `:copen` command, one can approach the issue in two ways.

**1.** Use the commands that directly alter window splitting directions
(see `:help :vertical` and below until the “Closing a window” paragraph).

For instance, consider the commands:

```
:botright copen
```

or

```
:botright cwindow
```

to make the quickfix window open as the bottommost one, or even:

```
:vertical topleft cwindow
```

to open it to the top left of the current window.

These commands can be shortened to `:bo cope`, `:bo cw`, and `:vert to cw`, respectively. Also, one can, of course, create a short mapping or
a custom command for their quick invocation.

**2.** Alternatively, move the quickfix window to the bottom of the window
layout using an auto-command:

```
:autocmd FileType qf wincmd J
```

This trigger takes advantage of the fact that the quickfix window can
be easily distinguished by its file-type, `qf`. The `wincmd J` command
is equivalent to the
[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>]
shortcut sequence instructing Vim to move the current window to the
very bottom of the screen (see `:help :wincmd` and `:help ^WJ`).

Comment: well, ":bo cope" does work and is fairly short.  It would be nice if I could just set a default.  The other option is to just use the taglist on the left like I guess most people do.  I kind of like it on the right side

Comment: @dreyln I came up with another way to solve the problem.  Take a look at the second approach in the updated answer.

Comment: The `wincmd J` could also be placed directly on ~/.vim/ftplugin/qt.vim along with any other customizations for this filetype.

Comment: @mMontu:  Of course, one can arrange that customization as a filetype plugin.  See `:help ftplugin` for information about writing filetype plugins.

Comment: awesome! I wanted to make the quickfix window span the full width by default (the vim default is to take the rightmost window of a vertical split). your `autocmd` did it just fine. But I was wondering...how did you find out about that? I tried to find s.th. in the documentation but couldn't turn up anything beyond `:botright copen`?

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution! I put "autocmd FileType qf wincmd J" in my .vimrc, then all new quickfix windows will occur at the bottom by default. Everything works fine!

Comment: When using autocmd, `vert copen` will still put the qf window down, use `Ctrl W L` to move to vertical split

Answer (score 4):

By default, Vim opens the new window above the current one for horizontal splits, and to the left of the current one for vertical splits (`:help opening-window`). You can customize this behavior like most other things in Vim:

make the new window appear below the current window.

```
:set splitbelow
```

make the new window appear on the right.

```
:set splitright
```

Comment: the normal default does not seem to apply for the quickfix window.  Also, :set splitbelow had no effect.  Quickfix window still appeared below and to the right